# Remove <ul> from wp_nav_menu() wordpress

Tags: menus, navigation

I am using the theme Twenty Thirteen and am using `wp_nav_menu()` to display menu items. I need to remove the container `<div>` and `<ul>` from `wp_nav_menu()`. I tried this:

```
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
```

Output recieved:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="#">aboutus</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="#">contactus</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-15"><a href="#">testimonials</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But it's not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: Define "not working". Is output not affected at all by customizing these parameters?

Comment: yes. The container and ul are still displaying.

Comment: Double check for "dumb" things? If you are editing right template, if you have any possible caching disabled, etc.

Comment: Tested, and there is no `ul`. Something else is going wrong.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information to answer this question. What is the output rendered by the above code? Is a nav menu assigned to the indicated theme_location, or is the fallback being output? Regarding "not working": what is not happening that you expect to happen, or what is happening unexpectedly?

Comment: Please refer my edited question for the output rendered by the above code.